# Add Variable header and footer to multipage PDF in Reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, header, footer, reportlab

I am trying to add variable headers and footers to a multipage PDF in reportlab. I am using pageTemplate to add the header and footer. The code is as below. I want to add a different header content every time I break the page like "page 1 header" on page 1, "page 2" header on page 2, and so on. The "onLaterPages" just lets me keep the same header content on all pages.

How can I achieve this using reportlab?

```
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
footerstyle = ParagraphStyle(
    name='myfooter',
    fontName='Helvetica',
    fontSize=9,
    leading=10,
    alignment=TA_RIGHT
)


def footer(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    P = Paragraph("%d" % doc.page,
              style=footerstyle)
    w, h = P.wrap(doc.width, doc.bottomMargin)
    P.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin, h)
    canvas.restoreState()


def header(canvas, doc, content):
    canvas.saveState()
    w, h = content.wrap(doc.width, doc.topMargin)
    content.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin, doc.height + doc.bottomMargin + doc.topMargin - h - 0.3 * 
    cm)
    canvas.restoreState()


def header_and_footer(canvas, doc, header_content):
    header(canvas, doc, header_content)
    footer(canvas, doc)


def create_table(filename, data, image_list):
     image_list = []
     PAGESIZE = pagesizes.portrait(pagesizes.A4)
     

    headstyle = ParagraphStyle(
        name='MyHeader',
        fontName='Helvetica-Bold',
        fontSize=12,
        leading=10
    )

    Story = []

    Story.append(Spacer(1, 20))

    table = Table(data, hAlign='LEFT', repeatRows=1)

    table.setStyle(TableStyle([
        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.lightblue),
        ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.5, '#CFEAD4'),
        ('ALIGN', (1, 1), (-1, -1), 'RIGHT')
    ]))

    Story.append(table)
    Story.append(PageBreak())

    pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(filename, pagesize=PAGESIZE, leftMargin=2.2 * cm, rightMargin=2.2 * cm,
                        topMargin=1.5 * cm, bottomMargin=2.5 * cm)

    for image in image_list:
        im = Image(image, width=pdf.width, height=pdf.height - 1 * cm)
        im.hAlign = 'LEFT'
        Story.append(Spacer(1, 10))
        Story.append(im)
        Story.append(PageBreak())


    frame = Frame(pdf.leftMargin, pdf.bottomMargin, pdf.width, pdf.height, id='normal')
    header_content = Paragraph('<img src=image.png valign="top" height="40" width ="70"/> '
                           'This is header', styles['Normal'])

    template = PageTemplate(id='test', frames=frame, onPage=partial(header_and_footer, 
                header_content=header_content))
    pdf.addPageTemplates([template])


    pdf.build(Story, onFirstPage=partial(header_and_footer, header_content=header_content), 
              onLaterPages=partial(header_and_footer, header_content=header_content))
```

Comment: I used NextPageTemplate() and it is producing dynamic headers.